# Network location provider at "https://www.googleapis.com/”: ERR CONNECTION TIMED OUT

Tags: javascript

When trying to use the browser's geolocation feature with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(), I encounter an error message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/': ERR CONNECTION TIMED OUT." How can I resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReIYS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).